# Ionic 2, use google maps in ion-segments

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a slight problem. Google maps is not showing in ionic 2 segments but showing outside of segments. I am using the following code,

```
 <div [ngSwitch]="report_details">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'details'">
        <div #map id="map"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried the following solutions but did not work:

1. use height and width of 100% on outer div.
2. use timeout on map load function.

Comment: Is there any problem reported on console?

Comment: You should add more info and code to make your problem clear. Where is your segment code for example ?

Comment: @SagarKulkarni nothing is reported on console.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby my segments are initialized in header. Something like this

      `<ion-toolbar> 
   <ion-segment mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="report_details">
       <ion-segment-button value="details" (ionSelect)="loadMap()">
         Details
       </ion-segment-button>
       <ion-segment-button value="employees">
         Employees
       </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
   </ion-toolbar>` 

and the above div is in content

Comment: Please update your question and provide full html and ts of what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and break the map out into its own page and use the selector to load it in via the ngSwitch directive. That way you could work with the ionic hooks like ionViewDidEnter() and ionViewWillEnter();

in the console.

```
ionic generate page map
```

then in your HTML try using something like this.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="report_details">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'details'">
       <page-map #map id="map"></page-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

map.ts

```
ionicViewDidEnter(){
    // initiate map here
}
```

then you can do whatever you want in the map.ts/map.html and it will hook onto its own navCtrl in order to have much more flexibility.

Comment: i have tried but its not working. Its the same result nothing is displaying

Comment: well dang, how are you initializing the map in your ts?

Comment: i am using a function and initializing it at ionViewDidLoad() function. i have also tried it initializing in contructor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you point out, Google Maps is showing perfectly outside segments. So following the approach suggested [by biranchi125 in Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-segment-div-google-map-not-showing/94086/2) you can place the map outside the segments and handle when to show it whith the selection variable, like this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="report_details">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'details'">
    <!-- you can place other elements here if you want -->
  </div>
  <div [style.display]="report_details == 'details' ? 'block' : 'none'">
     <div #map id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and it works : )