# IONIC 3 - <ion-segment> <div> Google Map not showing

Tags: css, google-maps, ionic2, segment, ionic3

I am experiencing a problem showing a map in my page.
This is my code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Cerca
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="mySegment">
      <ion-segment-button value="Mapa">
        Mapa
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="Lista">
        Lista
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div [ngSwitch]="mySegment">
    <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;" *ngSwitchCase="'Mapa'" (click)="openBestofferdetailPage(offer)">

    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Lista'">
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let offer of offersmodelArray" (click)="openBestofferdetailPage(offer)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
          <img src="{{offer.imageoffer}}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <p style="font-size:50%;">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <span item-left>{{offer.cityprovider}}</span>
              <span item-left>({{offer.distanceToProvider}} km)</span>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col right text-right>
              <s>
                <span item-right>{{offer.oldprice}}</span>
              </s>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <span item-left>{{offer.sold}}</span>
              <span item-left>comprados</span>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col right text-right>
              <b><p style="font-size:70%;" style="color:green">
        <span item-right>{{offer.newprice}}</span>
      </p></b>
        </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        </p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The default option is "Mapa" however it doesn't show the map, I guess is an issue related to the position setup and the `<ion-segment>` but I would appreciate your help on understanding where I can make the change.

Just as a complementary information if I set the map outside the content the map is being showed without any problem

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

I saw some related question but without answer
[Ionic 2, use google maps in ion-segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203791/ionic-2-use-google-maps-in-ion-segments)

Please your help

Comment: Does the map get shown when you remove *ngSwitchCase="'Mapa'" from its div ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It seems <div [ngSwitch]="mySegment"> it is showed on top of the map, at least this is my understanding. There should a way to make this <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div> on top to be showed